# TSM104W Voltage Reference

Tags: operational-amplifier, zener, voltage-reference

Hi I am trying to design with the TSM104W, which is a 4 package rail-to-rail OpAmps, with a built in voltage reference. This is the package pinout:

[image]

I see that the four Op-Amps are supplied through pins 4 and 13, but also pin 13 is the anode for what I think is a Zener diode, I am having trouble understanding how to actually use this voltage reference.

This is the part of the [datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/fe16/0900766b80db28c7.pdf) that tells the reference data:

[image]

I want to undestand how this voltage reference actually is and how to design with it, also I want to know if this IC could be used on a single supply application (Vcc- connected to ground).

Does voltage regulation is achieved with a circuit similar to a LM317 Voltage Regulator?, I would really aprecciate some hint on this. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I think I have found a similar Voltage reference in a stand alone package, TL431 or TL432. Comparing both datasheets is easy to see that the nomenclature used is the same.

TL431 [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tl432.pdf):
[image]

Would it be ok to design with the TSM104W using the schematics shown on the TLA431 datasheet?

For example:

[image]

Comment: So no one knows anything about these voltage regulators?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you use the TSM104W reference the same way as a TL431.

Comment: Thanks @Null, It was hard to find a datasheet without knowing what I was searching for, but it is good to know that at least I found something useful.